# When is the Lie Bracket of a Lie Algebra of a Lie Group *not* a commutator?

Tags: group-theory, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

I know that the Lie bracket of a *matrix* Lie group is always the matrix commutator.

However since the 'raw' left-invariant vector fields (defined in terms of differential operators) carry a commutator, I'm struggling to figure out when the Lie bracket would not have to be represented by a commutator?

Actually is the adjoint representation an example?

Comment: By Ado's Theorem every Lie bracket can be realised by a commutator $[A,B]=AB-BA$.

Comment: But what is an example of when it is not realised as a commutator?

Comment: I mean I thought you've said that you CAN CHOOSE to represent it by a commutator always. I'm simply asking of an example where you choose not to (eventhough it could have been chosen to be a commutator)

Comment: Take the Lie algebra with basis $\{x,y\}$ in dimension two with Lie bracket $[x,y]=x$. This is not given by a commutator (but can be realized as matrix algebra with commutator as Lie bracket). In fact, the "product" $xy$ is not even defined. You cannot multiply vectors. So $xy-yx$ makes no sense at all.

Comment: You seem to be asking about the concrete definition where you say the lie algebra of a lie group is the space of left-invariant vector fields. Then the lie bracket $[x, y]$ is indeed $xy - yx$, with the essential caveat that $xy$ and $yx$ are not even in the space, i.e., they are not vector fields, they are differential operators of order $2$ in general. For a genera lie algebra DietrichBurde is right and the individual products $xy$ and $yx$ are not even defined so the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Another example may help you. Take $G = SL_n(R)$. Then the lie algebra is $sl_n(R)$, the space of trace-zero matrices, and the bracket is $[A, B] = AB-BA$, but again note that $AB$ and $BA$ are outside of the space in general (they need not have zero trace) so it's not really fair to call this a commutator.

Comment: Would the adjoint representation of ad(x)(y) = [ad(x)] matrix * vector (y) over basis matrices could as a case where it isn't a commutator?

Comment: Be more explicit with your example. I do not wish to *guess* what your confusion about left invariant fields is, only to be told "no, that's *not* what I had in mind"...

Comment: Are you cool with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation#Adjoint_representation_of_a_Lie_algebra)?