# Why do we represent Lie bracket in adjoint representation by matrix-vector multiplication not matrix commutation.

Tags: group-theory, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

For a Lie Group G we can represent it as a subset of $GL(V)$, and represent it's lie algebra as a subset of $End(V)$ (where the Lie Bracket is expressed as the commutation of these $End(V)$.

For instance SU(2) can be represented as a subset of $GL(\mathbb{C^2})$ and su(2) as a subset of $End(\mathbb{C^2})$ where the Lie Bracket is calculated by commuting these matrices.

Now for the adjoint representation of the Lie Algebra, for su(2) we calculated $ 3 \times 3$ matrices representing ad(x) such that ad(X)(Y) is calculated by multipling the matrix for ad(X) by the vector for Y.

My question is why don't we still represent the Lie Bracket by matrix commutations? For instance, the Adjoint representation represents the group G as a subset of $GL(L(G))$ so why can't we play the same game as in my first paragraph and represent the Lie Algebra as a subset of $End(L(G))$ where the Lie Bracket is again expressed as a matrix commutator?

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4302155/when-is-the-lie-bracket-of-a-lie-algebra-of-a-lie-group-not-a-commutator). You don't have to post each time a new question in one day. You can also add this to your old question. If $Z(L)=0$, then ${\rm ad}(L)\cong L$, so we have a matrix algebra anyway.

Comment: But actually $ad([x,y]) = ad(x)ad(y)-ad(y)ad(x)$ which you can write as $[ad(x), ad(y)]$ with the last bracket being the commutator in $End(L)$, so what more can one want? Of course $(ad(x))(y)$ is something different, but they already come from different sets: $ad(x) \in End(L), y\in L$, so there is no hope to define any Lie bracket between those two.