# Lie Algebra Representation Definition Clarification

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds, lie-derivative

My groups lecture notes define a Lie Algebra representation as a linear map to the endomorphisms of V:

$$r: L \rightarrow End(V) $$

such that r is a Lie Algebra homomorphism (i.e. it preserves the Lie Bracket and the vector space structure)

$$r[\eta, \xi] = [r(\eta), r(\xi)]$$

My question is simply: does the $[]$ on the right hand side of the final equation necessarily mean the *usual* matrix commutator, or does it mean *any* sort of commutator (so long as it preseves the Lie Bracket structure)?

(I'm assuming it is the latter, since the adjoint representation does not make use of the usual matrix commutator, but simply matrix-vector multiplication)

(Although I am slightly confused, since in the adjoint representation $[X,Y]$ is represented by the $ad_X$ matrix multiplying a $Y$ vector, so the $Y$ vector does not seem to being represented by a matrix in $End(V)$, but maybe the 'representation' only means the matrix part (since it describes $X$ and its action) and we have just defined the commutator in this framework to mean multiply by a vector?)

Comment: The former although there's no need to write anything as matrices. The set of endomorphisms has a natural Lie bracket defined by the commutator $[\phi,\psi] := \phi\circ\psi - \psi\circ\phi$. Lie algebra representations are just homomorphisms into such a space (i.e. viewing elements of the Lie algebra as linear maps on a vector space).

Comment: Note in the adjoint rep the Lie algebra is also the vector space so $\mathrm{ad}: \mathfrak{g} \to \mathrm{End}(\mathfrak{g} )$ is our representation defined by $\mathrm{ad}(X) := [X, \cdot]$. If we wanted to write this as a matrix (we probably don't) it would be a  $\dim \mathfrak{g} \times\dim \mathfrak{g} $ matrix.

Comment: But in the case of the adjoint rep, aren't you saying right there that we are using $ad(X)*Y$ *not* $ad(X)ad(Y) - ad(Y)ad(X)$ to represent the Lie Bracket?

Comment: This is my main issue. I agree that the set of endomorphisms always can use a Lie bracket defined by the commutator (as you said), but my confusion here is that, in the adjoint representation, we use ad(X) matrix * Y vector to represent the Lie Bracket (not the commutation of the ad(X) and ad(Y) matrices)

Comment: I'm very happy that we could *also* use the commutation of the ad(X) and ad(Y) matrices (as discussed in my other question). But I just want to clarify here that in the usual adjoint representation we don't use the matrix commutator, and therefore in my OP the [] on the right hand side *can* be something other than the matrix commutator

Comment: You don't need to use matrix at all in the adjoint representation: it send $X \in \mathfrak g$ to $ad_X \in End(\mathfrak g) $, where $ad_X (Y) = [X, Y]$

Comment: Okay I agree that matrices are not needed, but $ad_X (Y)$ is still not the same as $ad_X ad_Y - ad_Y ad_X$ so surely we can agree this bracket is not a usual commutator?

Comment: $ad_X Y$ is an element in $\mathfrak g$, while $ad_X ad_Y - ad_Y ad_X$ is in $End (\mathfrak g)$. How can they be the same?

Comment: Yes I am not saying that they are the same. I'm saying that they are 2 different ways of representing the Lie Algebra. In one you represent $[X,Y]=Z$ with $ad_X(Y) = Z$, in the other with $ad_X ad_Y - ad_Y ad_X = ad_Z$. My only question is, in the definition in my OP, for the first way to fit its definition of a 'representation', we need the [] on the right hand side (in the definition) to mean *any* way of representing the bracket (and not necessarily a usual commutator, as ad_X(Y) is not). Do you agree?

Comment: The Lie algebra structure on $End (\mathfrak g)$ is $[A, B] = A\circ B - B \circ A$. We are using this one in the adjoint representation.

Comment: Ohhh, okay then. Then why does $ad_X(Y) = [X,Y]$ also work? It seems like you are 'mixing and matching' elements from 2 different representations of the Lie Algebra

Comment: How is $ad_XY$ even a Lie bracket on $End(\mathfrak g)$? $X, Y$ are not even in $End(\mathfrak g)$....

Comment: Isn't this the same confusion I tried to talk you out of with my comment to your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4302281/96384 ?